# Trouble with adding a new file as view in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add index.py as a view in Django but I keep getting Views Don't Exist error.
However, it works with views.py, which is in the same folder as index.py
Do I need to generate index.pyc?

Here is my urls.py:

```
# urls.py handles the request from client. 
# This is the first file that controller looks at when client

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'Work_manager.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url (r'^$', 'TasksManager.views.index.page'),
    url (r'^index$', 'TasksManager.views.index.page'),
)
```

index.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# View for index page.
def page (request) :
    return HttpResponse ("Hello world!" )
```

Thank you

Comment: Just curious, how should I write my code if I want to reroute from views.py to index.py?

Answer (score 1):

```
url (r'^$', 'TasksManager.index.page'),
url (r'^index$', 'TasksManager.index.page'),
```

No need to add **views** module name in your **url** as your url will map directly it **page**  function in **index** module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess the code in tutorial was wrong.

Comment: Just curious, how should I write my code if I want to reroute from views.py to index.py?

Comment: Well in django views are just a python module so if you want to use some functionality from index module just import it in your views module, call the function from index module that you have imported inside your main function that was mapped from your url.
You can't redirect from views to index because the function which is redirected from your url module must return a httpresponse. If you want i can include an example for you in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It will be great if you can add an example.